# Proving by Cauchy's definition $\lim_{x\to 0} x^2\cos x=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, proof-verification

> Prove by definition that $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} x^2\cos x=0$$

So take $\delta=\sqrt\epsilon$, and from definition we have: $|x|<\delta\Rightarrow|x^2|<\delta^2\Rightarrow|x^2\cos x|<\delta^2\cos x$ and since $-1<\cos x<1$ we have $|x^2\cos x|<\delta^2=\epsilon$.

Is multiplying by $\cos x$ and then since it's bounded it's smaller correct?

Comment: Since $|\cos(x)| \le 1$ you can say that for all $x$, $0 < |x| < \delta$ implies $|x^2\cos(x)| \le x^2 < \delta^2 = \epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying $\cos x$ you take the risk of multiplying by negative numbers and changing the inequality, since $-1\leq \cos x \leq 1$.

On the other hand, you may notice that $|\cos x| \leq 1$ then from what you did

$$|x^2\cos x - 0| = |x^2||\cos x| \leq x^2 < \delta^2 = \epsilon$$